# Hide TextBox Caret in Windows 8

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-8, microsoft-metro, caret

I have a TextBox. It will represent a single digit. When I focus it, I show the border to notice it is selected and I can write on it. I intercepted OnKeyDown event to change the TextBox's content for the digit key I press.

I want to hide the caret, because I don't want the caret "to lie" seeming I can write wherever place in the TextBox I want.

I tried with `IsReadOnly = true`, and it hides the caret. The KeyDown event continues working (because I did with AddHandler function), but when I focus the TextBox, the touch keyboard doesn't appear.

I want to hide the caret, but to show the touch keyboard at the same time.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `microsoft-metro` is a ui style not a programming language - what are you coding in C#/VB/??? I suspect you'll need to create a control which inherits from `TextBox` and override the `OnPaint` event to suppress the drawing of the caret. Once you tell us what language you're using, we can give you some examples

Comment: I am coding with C#. In [tag:microsoft-metro] you use Windows.UI namespace for controls, and it has some restrictions. For example, it doesn't exist any OnPaint method or equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking of that, you're right - it's WPF based.

Comment: If the text box behaves as you describe, why does it matter where the caret is? No matter where the user places the caret, typing will always result in the same action: the content will be replaced.

Comment: The caret can be bebore the number or after the number. It might confuse the user. I prefer to mark the whole number with painting the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible under a c#/xaml winRT app.
Only possible for wpf or silverlight app using the CaretBrush property.

[Check here for confirmation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/26bc26d1-574d-48c1-9a00-5096c55cdbd3)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide or even change the color of the Caret in WinRT/Windows 8. You can change the background color of the `TextBox` itself but that doesn't really hide Caret.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed when I give it a Background color, the cursor goes away. While this is not what I want, it will make the cursor go away. I am working in 8.1.
Example:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource _textBoxStyle1}" 
Text="{Binding AddRow.Code, Mode=TwoWay}" 
Width="220" 
BorderThickness="0" 
Grid.Column="1" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Margin="10,0" 
Background="#40FFFFFF" 
Foreground="BurlyWood"/>

<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="_textBoxStyle1" >
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource _standardFont}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="38" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="BurlyWood" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
</Style>

<x:String x:Key="_standardFont">Arial</x:String>
```